# Buttons on screen do not work unless simulator is of the XS variety

Tags: ios, swift, nodes, compatibility, skspritenode

essentially I had the app running fine, but then when I tried to run it on any other simulator other than the XS simulator in Xcode the main menu buttons no longer work and I do not no where to look for the error since nothing is throwing any errors. Furthermore when I put print statements inside the nodes, the print statement prints to the console which tells me the screen is detecting the selection, but for some reason the code just does not run. Which is odd because it is a simple if else statement inside a function being called, so I see no reason it should not run as well.

```
 var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bgImage")
var newGameButtonNode:SKSpriteNode!
var difficultyButtonNode:SKSpriteNode!
var difficultyLabelNode:SKLabelNode!
var gameModeNode:SKSpriteNode!
var gameModeLabel:SKLabelNode!
var gameMode:Int = 1


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    background.zPosition = -4
    background.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
    background.scale(to: (self.scene?.size)!)
    addChild(background)
    newGameButtonNode = self.childNode(withName: "newGame") as? SKSpriteNode
    difficultyButtonNode = self.childNode(withName: "difficultyButton") as? SKSpriteNode
    difficultyLabelNode = self.childNode(withName: "difficultyLabel") as? SKLabelNode
    gameModeNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "toggle")
    gameModeLabel = self.childNode(withName: "gameModeLabel") as! SKLabelNode

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "hard") {
        difficultyLabelNode.text = "HARD MODE"
    } else {
        difficultyLabelNode.text = "EASY MODE"
    }
    gameMode = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "mode")
    if gameMode == 1{
        gameModeLabel.text = "Crypto Catch"
        userDefaults.set(1, forKey: "mode")
    } else if gameMode == 2 {
        gameModeLabel.text = "Crypto Invaders"
        userDefaults.set(2, forKey: "mode")
    } else if gameMode == 3 {
        gameModeLabel.text = "Crypto Galiga"
        userDefaults.set(3, forKey: "mode")
    }

    difficultyButtonNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "toggleYellow")
    difficultyButtonNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    difficultyButtonNode.scale(to: CGSize(width: 250 , height: 250))
    newGameButtonNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"playGameYellow")
    newGameButtonNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gameModeNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gameModeNode.scale(to: CGSize(width: 250, height: 250))
    gameModeNode.name = "gameModeNode"
    newGameButtonNode.scale(to: CGSize(width: 250, height: 250))
    difficultyButtonNode.position =  CGPoint(x: (scene?.size.width)!/2-125, y: (scene?.size.height)!/2-150)
    newGameButtonNode.position = CGPoint(x: (scene?.size.width)!/2-125, y:  (scene?.size.height)!/2+150)
    difficultyLabelNode.position = CGPoint(x: (scene?.size.width)!/2, y: (scene?.size.height)!/2-175)
    gameModeLabel.position = CGPoint(x: (scene?.size.width)!/2, y: (scene?.size.height)!/2-175 - 300)
    self.addChild(gameModeNode)
    gameModeNode.position = CGPoint(x: (scene?.size.width)!/2-125, y: (scene?.size.height)!/2-175 - 250)


}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    if let location = touch?.location(in: self){
        let nodesArray = self.nodes(at: location)
        if nodesArray.first?.name == "newGame"{
            if gameMode == 1{
                let transition = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
                let gameSceneOB = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
                gameSceneOB?.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                self.view?.presentScene(gameSceneOB!, transition: transition)
            } else if gameMode == 2 {
                let transition = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
                let gameSceneOB = GameScene(fileNamed: "ShooterGame")
                gameSceneOB?.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                self.view?.presentScene(gameSceneOB!, transition: transition)

            } else if gameMode == 3 {
                let transition = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
                let gameSceneOB = GameScene(fileNamed: "cryptoGal")
                gameSceneOB?.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                self.view?.presentScene(gameSceneOB!, transition: transition)

            }

        } else if nodesArray.first?.name == "difficultyButton" {
            changeDifficulty()
        } else if nodesArray.first?.name == "gameModeNode"{
            toggleGameMode()

        }
    }
}
func changeDifficulty() {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if difficultyLabelNode.text  == "EASY MODE"{
        difficultyLabelNode.text = "HARD MODE"
        userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "hard")
    } else {
        difficultyLabelNode.text = "EASY MODE"
        userDefaults.set(false, forKey: "hard")
    }
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
func changeGameMode() {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if gameMode == 1{
        gameModeLabel.text = "Crypto Catch"
        userDefaults.set(1, forKey: "mode")
    } else if gameMode == 2 {
        gameModeLabel.text = "Crypto Invaders"
        userDefaults.set(2, forKey: "mode")
    } else if gameMode == 3 {
        gameModeLabel.text = "Crypto Galiga"
        userDefaults.set(3, forKey: "mode")
    }
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
func toggleGameMode(){
    if gameMode == 1{
        gameMode = 2
    } else if gameMode == 2 {
        gameMode = 3
    } else if gameMode == 3 {
        gameMode = 1
    }
    changeGameMode()
}
```

Comment: BTW it would be really common, to do the buttons/etc simply in "normal" iOS, and only show the game itself using an SKScene.

Comment: **Wait** - generally speaking spriteKit/Metal etc JUST DOES NOT WORK in simulator!  You have to build to a phone!   It could be only working "coincidentally" in the new XS simulator.  That's all it is.  Build to phones only.

Comment: Im not using any auto layout constrains. In addition I know the buttons are being selected because I'm printing to the console when I touch them and can see that its detecting the selection.

Comment: right @Alec , answer is below!  very simple ...

Comment: Interesting.  So i can rest assured it will work on  any iPhone model? Sorry if i sound dense.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking spriteKit/Metal etc JUST DOES NOT WORK in simulator!

You have to build to a phone!

It could be only working "coincidentally" in the new XS simulator. That's all it is. Build to phones only.